# How to see where my website is running after creating a container using docker image?

Tags: docker

I have created a container using an image which hosts a simple tomcat application.
I used this command:

```
docker run -d -p 7992:80 <Image_Name>
```

It ran successfully and gave me the container ID.
Now I have tried hitting `http://<host_ip>:7992` as well as `http://<container_id>` URL. But it keeps saying site cannot be reached.

Am I hitting the wrong IP or what? Where will I see my website?
Please comment if any more information is required.

Comment: Is iptables (or whatever network filter you might be using) allowing port 7992 through? Also, your tomcat image does `EXPOSE 80`, right?

Comment: Yes the image exposes port 80. I have to check the 7992 port though.

Comment: Yes 7992 is exposed, still site not reached error.

Comment: It's difficult to say more without more information, such as the Dockerfile (or name of the image if it's a public image).

Comment: Tomcat default port is 8080, may be you just need to run docker remapping port 7992:8080. Anyway, supply the output of "docker inspect".

Comment: Also ask Docker to show the port bindings, e.g. `docker inspect --format '{{.NetworkSettings.Ports}}' your-container-id`

Comment: Two possible reasons. If you are using docker swarm, you need to connect to the manager. If you are using boot2docker, run this and try eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
docker port <container_id>
```